# How to create a Linux Ubuntu/OpenSUSE installer for my Java App?

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation, opensuse

as the topic goes,
how can I create an installer for my java application which can be easily install on both version of linux (Ubuntu/OpenSUSE) ?

As for dependency goes, can I add another installer such as "RPM" to an existing installer?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maven has an [RPM plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) and a [DEB plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/).